# С чего начать в Web-программировании?

Tags: веб-программирование

У меня к вам есть несколько вопросов. У меня есть цель сначала - это создать сайт, посвященный, например, физике, где я могу выкладывать книги по физике.

1) Прочитав кучу форумов, понял, что надо изучать HTML, CSS, JS, MySQL и что-нибудь еще с сайта, например, w3schools.com. Каждый из этих языков имеет свою задачу. Наверно еще неплохо прочитать какую-нибудь документацию по HTTP. 
А вот что дальше? Как практическую программу надо составить, чтобы расти, то есть начать сначала с веб-страницы, потом простенький сайт, потом сложный сайт, потом перейти к серверам, наверно или как-то по-другому? Ведь не тупо же выучить синтаксис языка и вуаля - все готово... Скажите, пожалуйста, на ваш взгляд, практическую прокачку или рост что ли следует придерживаться, чтобы в будущем влиться в какой-нибудь проект, пусть даже совсем небольшой? К вышеперечисленным языкам какие еще можно добавить (Node.js, Angular.js, PHP, Python, Ruby, xHTML, SVG, DOM и т.д.)? Я прекрасно понимаю, что каждый из них отвечает за какую-то конкретную функцию.

2) Что лучше использовать начинающему: Linux или Windows?
Потребуется ли использование в дальнейшем соответственно командной строки или терминала где-либо? Просто смотрю много сайтов, но непонятно: информации много, но вот целостности картины нет.

Comment: Фронтэнд и бекэнд разработчики занимаются совершенно разными вещами. Определитесь для начала, что вам ближе - браузер или сервер. В первом случае ОС не имеет значения, во втором знания линукса будут полезны.

Comment: Тем кому нужен просто сайт обычно пользуются статическими генераторами сайтов (например gohugo, jekyll и т.д.), это означает что для создания сайта запускается программа, которая считывает специальным образом расположенные по каталогам текстовые файлы и генерирует статические станицы со всеми стилями. А выкладывание книг которые вы не написали или которые не распространяются под Creative Commons лицензией повлекут последствия в виде гневных писем от правообладателей да и хостинг может удалить такую станицу.

Comment: А какие языки нужны для бекенд разработчика?

Answer (score 5):

WEB программирование начинается с языка разметки [HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml), это основа. Затем можно почитать на досуге [CSS](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss). В этом случае уже можно будет создать(или сверстать) web-страницу, этот файл будет с расширением HTML и любой браузер его поймет.
Для того, чтобы начать писать HTML и CSS достаточно программы [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Вторым шагом, захочется оживить страницу, добавить динамики так сказать. Тут уже начинается программирование [(Front-end)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_%D0%B8_back_end). Здесь неплохо изучить [JavaScript](http://learn.javascript.ru/). Фреймворки советовать не буду, когда понадобится сам поймёшь что тебе нужно.

Третьим захочется сделать так, чтобы страницы генерировались в зависимости от каких либо условий. Или например позволять пользователям взаимодействовать с сайтом (регистрация, общение, тесты и т.д.). Тут нам понадобится [PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php). На самом деле не обязательно PHP, есть много других языков, но я задачи на стороне сервера решаю именно на PHP. Чтобы писать код на PHP понадобится сервер (или упростим, нам нужен [хостинг](https://beget.com/p54123)), хотя можно развернуть это дело и у себя дома, но какой смысл, если мы хотим размещать сайт в интернете. Кстати говоря PHP в голом виде это круто, но ещё больше крутости будет после изучения [SQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) для общения с базой данных - обладая таким багажом уже можно замутить довольно крутые, серьёзные вещи. Но будем двигаться дальше, поняв как работает протокол HTTP - а это довольно просто, мы можем задействовать [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). Познав все эти прелести ты будешь ограничен лишь своей фантазией!

И так на будущее, многие вещи уже изобретены и ими можно пользоваться, чтобы сэкономить время:

Чтобы не заморачиваться с дизайном - [Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-4.ru/)

Ускорить разработку на JS - [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Парсим сайты легко и быстро - [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Пишем ботов, парсим и многое другое с супер мощным оружием [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/)

2 извечный вопрос Linux или Windows? Основную часть времени лично я работаю под Windows, но если сильно прижмет, а такое бывает, то можно использовать Linux. Поэтому думаю, что Linux - это полезно и иногда даже удобно. Но Windows привычнее.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Спасибо за внимание! А вот есть такие языки - не языки, например, DOM. Что это такое? Я просто на сайте w3school.com увидел, посчитал сайт лучше всяких книг.

Comment: Как вы относетесь к сайту w3schools.com? Благо английским владею на уровне, то есть читаю спокойно в принципе

Comment: О том, что такое DOM можно почитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-nodes это будет особо интересно в процессе изучения JavaScript.

А что касается w3schools.com, не пользуюсь этим ресурсом.

Comment: А нужно ли знание photoshop? Я просто решил посмотреть портфолио некоторых людей, и увидел там знание этой программы. А что такое LESS, SASS?

Comment: Основные знания photoshop не помешают никому, даже бухгалтеру, а уж тем более программисту. Но профессиональные знания photoshop нужны дизайнеру. LESS – это надстройка над CSS которая просто делает CSS функциональней. SASS - это  такая штука, упрощающая написание когда CSS, если более профессионально то SASS вводит дополнительный уровень абстракциии

Comment: А полугода хватит для того, чтобы в самую захудалую конторку устроиться?